# how to play MLV video on ubuntu

Tags: video-player

I have Ubuntu 17.10 and i want to play the `MLV` video format.

i tried the default video player and `VLC` and doesn't work.

i tried also the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc-plugin-libde265
```

and the result that this package not found

Comment: Were did you find this command ?

Comment: See http://www.magiclantern.fm/forum/index.php?topic=9560.0

Answer (score 2):

Magic Lantern Video (mlv) is an obscure raw video format and is not going to be natively supported in most applications. Generally you'll have to convert it to another format like dv to have players like VLC support it.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a lot of resources, tools and documentation on how to handle MLV files here: [ML RAW-tools & more how to deal with .raw/mlv & cDNG files in Linux](http://www.magiclantern.fm/forum/index.php?topic=9335.0)

Good luck!